# Best practices for using Own API for client and server?

Tags: php, database-design, architecture

I am creating an applicaton in PHP with MVC based framework. I am exposing a web API for the mobile apps.

The same mobile interface is to be created in web application also. *So*:

*For creating the web interface, can I use the API created for mobile app with HTTP request?*

**OR**

*Model methods are exposed, so can we use the model instead of calling and connecting with the API in same server?*

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends , if it is your internal product, and you are the only user of API, it is better to  expose function base API. eg: addUser, deleteUser.

If you want some one else to use the API and create some application (with different logic depending on their own need) give them model based access. As far as I know functional API's are generally created and exposed. Because this kinds of API saves the number of webservice call and hides the logic underneath it.

edit

if you mean calling the webservice internally ... Ideally design should be such that ..their should be a delegate method that consists of core logic, then that core logic function can be called from your api as well as controller. Calling webservice internally will be a unnecessasary performance overhead. Though you can do that in small size application, but is not at all good solution.

If your model layer holds business logic, though It should be Ideally a seperate layer ...then you should consider using model.

Comment: Model is not going to be exposed. I am creating an API with a controller and also need to create web interface. So for creating that interface, which is the best way?

If I am using API, in the controller, I need to connect with my own API which is a part of the same application.

Comment: hmmm In that case ... you mean calling the webservice internally ... I deally design should be such that ..their should be a delegate method that consists of core logic, then that core logic function can be called from your api as well as controller. Calling webservice internally will be a unnecessasary performance overhead. Though you can do that in small size application, but is not at all good solution

Comment: Kindly let me know if I have understood your problem correctly this time. If yes, will update it to answer

Comment: Yes, in our application, model holds the entire business level logic and that is using by the API. So in MVC, model is available and shared for controller.

Comment: ideally model and business layer should be seperate. In your case better use model